# Make server side rendered React app work offline with service worker

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, server-side-rendering, workbox

I would like to know how to resolve the following failed Lighthouse audits for a server side rendered React application.

- Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline
- `start_url` does not respond with a 200 when offline

[image: lighthouse audit result]

I am able to generate and register a service worker using the [workbox-webpack-plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin) and precache the javascript and stylesheets.

However, since the app is server side rendered, there is no `index.html` to cache and the app is unable to "respond with a 200 when offline". Concretely, when I go offline and refresh the web page, I am met with browsers' offline message.

I think a possible solution is to generate an app shell (an html document containing the app ready to be rendered on the client side), cache that app shell and use it when offline. However I do not know where to start. Any ideas, or alternative suggestions?

Comment: working with workbox, you should find what you need here : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#provide_a_fallback_response_to_a_route, you just need to find what to display when offline, often I use an offline page `mysite.com/offline` but it's up to you !

Comment: @ekans thanks, your suggestion was helpful. If you post it as an answer, I will accept.